# Does Uninstalling a secondary HDD (Device Manager) stops it from spinning?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, uninstall

I have 2 HDDs and the secondary one is 3 years old, so I don't want it to keep spinning all the time (to maximize its life).
I tried setting power options to turn it off after 1 minute but sometimes a process wakes it for no apparent reason (there's no pagefile or applications on that drive) and the last mysterious process to wake it was Chrome, and performance monitor shows that it's accessing a file called wikipedia offline (why on earth would chrome want to access this file?!)

So, does this method (Device Manager -> Uninstall Drive) stops it completely from spinning until I scan for hardware changes again, or will it require restart? Is it safe or not?

Comment: What you want wouldn't increase the device's lifespan because the process of powering on its just as harmful then accessing the drive.

Comment: You're tilting at windmills. My suggestion is to leave it alone and to make sure that you perform regularly occurring backups of the drive if it has data on it that is important to you.

Comment: I'll use it as backup (not sure if that's wise cause it has some bad sectors, but it's all I have now) I guess the only solution is to plug it just when I need to backup something as I noticed that whatever I do to disable it, power it down or hotswap it, it has to spin every time I start the computer.